# iOS >> How to schedule timing based events that are not user action related

Tags: ios, benchmarking

In my app I wish to have in a certain view a list of images that change on a UIImageView; something like an automated "presentation".

I'm looking for a way to perform this "automation". The idea is that I will have a list of images, each one will also have a timing property >> something like "Image_1" + "00:00", "Image_2" + "00:27", "Image_3" + "01:04" etc...
I guess I should probably use an NSDictionary to hold the file names and timing.

The only thing I'm not clear about, is **which method I should use to "catch" the timing property from the NSDictionary and relate to them as "events"** that run my code that will deal with the image change.

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to fire after the required time, or you could use [`– performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a). `NSTimer` is probably the best option because you can cancel them if the view goes away.

1. Create a timer to trigger after the first delay.
2. When the timer fires, change the image (using a nice transition if you like) and set up the timer for the next delay.
3. If the view is removed, cancel the current timer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `NSTimer` you can set it to fire at a set time or at intervals, by using the current date. Id have NSTimer call a method which changes the images.

```
- (id)initWithFireDate:(NSDate *)date interval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

This declaration method should do the trick

[NSTimer Developer Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Hope this helps